# def get_absolute_urls(self): not working ,Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

when I click the post title it is supposed to go to the post detail(detail.html) but it's not working, how do i fix this?

Here is Model.py
class Post(models.Model):
.......

```
  def get_absolute_urls(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                        args=[self.publish.year,
                            self.publish.month,
                            self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns= [
    path('',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
]
```

Views.py

```
def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
    post= get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish_year= year,publish_month= month, publish_day= day)
    return render(request,'blog/detail.html',{'post':post})
```

list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Blog {% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<h1>My Blog</h1>
<p>this is working in list.html</p>
{% for post in posts %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
    </a>
</h2>

<p class="date">
    Published{{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>

{{ post.body| truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}


{% block content %}


<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p class="date">
    Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|linebreaks }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: The method name needs to be `get_absolute_url`, not `get_absolute_urls`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{% url 'get_absolute_urls' %}`

or

change your function name above your model `get_absolute_url` instead of `get_absolute_urls`

**Solution:**

> in models.py

```
 def get_absolute_url(self): # removed the letter s
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                        args=[self.publish.year,
                            self.publish.month,
                            self.publish.day, self.slug])
```

> in .html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Blog {% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<h1>My Blog</h1>
<p>this is working in list.html</p>
{% for post in posts %}
<h2>
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
    </a>
</h2>

<p class="date">
    Published{{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>

{{ post.body| truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```